# wxWidgets ContextMenu/Popup

Tags: c++, popup, contextmenu, wxwidgets, listcontrol

I have a **wxListCtrl** and I would like to make it so that when a user right click on an item to show up a **contextmenu/popup**.

> How can I do this with wxFormBuilder or programatically?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the event of type [`wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html) or `wxEVT_CONTEXT_MENU` (more general, thanks  vadz) and then pop up a [wxMenu](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html).

An example of this can be seen in the wxListCtrl sample, which can be found in `wxdir\samples\listctrl`. A short snippet modified from the sample should give you the right idea:

```
void MyListCtrl::OnRightClick(wxListEvent& event)
{
    // Show popupmenu at position
    wxMenu menu(wxT("Test"));
    menu.Append(LIST_ABOUT, wxT("&About"));
    PopupMenu(&menu, event.GetPoint());
}
```

Comment: This works but you might prefer to use `wxEVT_CONTEXT_MENU` for clarity and because it works for many kinds of windows and not just `wxListCtrl`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example in http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxMenu